# HttpCookieCollection.Add vs HttpCookieCollection.Set - Does the Request.Cookies collection get copied to the Response.Cookies collection?

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, httpresponse, httpcookie, httpcookiecollection

I just want to clear this up.

I know that if I have set a cookie on a previous request, it will show up in my `Request.Cookies` collection.

I want to update my existing Cookie.

Are the cookies from my `Request.Cookies` collection already copied to my `Response.Cookies` collection?  Do I need to add a new cookie with the same key using `Response.Cookies.Add()`, or do I need to use `Response.Cookies.Set()`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a difference:

- `Response.Cookies.Add()` will allow duplicate cookies to be set http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.add.aspx
- `Response.Cookies.Set()` will make sure the cookie is unique by first checking to ensure the cookie doesn't exist http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.set.aspx

Duplicate cookies typically requires extra handling to determine which is the most recent. I'm not sure of a case when you would want duplicate cookies on the same site, maybe someone else can chime in with an example

***Edit:*** In your case, you want to use set because you are updating.

Comment: Thanks - I also did some reflection and I realized I am asking the wrong question.  Please check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517595/what-is-the-best-practice-for-updating-a-cookie-that-was-set-on-a-previous-reques

Comment: this is badly documented. the [original documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.set(v=vs.110).aspx) includes the statement "Updates the value of an **existing** cookie in a cookie collection" which is just wrong because if the cookie does not exist, it is added. the [underlying code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpCookieCollection.cs,98) uses a `BaseAdd` call which updates existing keys and adds new keys.

Comment: I don't think one can have the confidence that code the document refers to in 2011 is the same code you have linked to that is 4.7.2.