# How to remove cookie in Hosted environment, which i works in local environment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I am using Web api with AngularJS as front end, I developed an app in local environment and everything works fine locally. But today I had to host my app on a server, and I suddenly can't remove a cookie which I could do locally:

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage UnAuthenticate()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["sessionId"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["sessionId"];
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("cacheToken");
    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

It works in IE, but it fails in Chrome.

Comment: use Response.SetCookie instead of Cookies.Add. Read this for comparision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517273/httpcookiecollection-add-vs-httpcookiecollection-set-does-the-request-cookies

Comment: It looks like this answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5517505/261560

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public virtual HttpResponseMessage UnAuthenticate()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["sessionId"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return null;
}
```