# Cookie expiry date not set

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Here is my `get`:

```
protected string Identifier
{
    get
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[IDENTIFIER_COOKIE];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            return cookie.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie(IDENTIFIER_COOKIE);
            cookie.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return cookie.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

When running my project locally, the cookie's expiry date is set as expected

[image: local]

But when I run it live, the cookie's expiry date is **When the browsing session ends**.

[image: live]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my page was served on HTTPS. I had to specifiy `cookie.Secure = true` for the expiry date to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything else, I suggest that you clear your cache and cookies.

```
protected string Identifier
{
    get
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies[IDENTIFIER_COOKIE];

        if (!cookie)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie(IDENTIFIER_COOKIE);
            cookie.Value = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }Cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

        return cookie.Value
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure you are not in private browsing mode.

Comment: I can't see the difference with my code. You don't clear anything, do you?

Comment: you used Cookies.Add which allow duplicate cookies to be set, in your case, you should use Cookies.Set. Additional reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517273/httpcookiecollection-add-vs-httpcookiecollection-set-does-the-request-cookies

Comment: `Cookies.Add` is used when the cookie doesn't exist in my case.