# Windows IE 10 crashed when printing from Report Manager SQL server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, internet-explorer-10

We have a problem with **Windows 7** in combination with **IE 10** and printing reports.
When we **print** a report from the Report Manager 'http:///reports' the browser **crashed** .
But  Windows 7 with different IE versions have no problem.
I tried the report manager from **SQL Server 2005** .
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 9.00.4035.00

The event log shows these message

Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, 
version: 10.0.9200.16736,time stamp: 0x5258c4cc
Faulting module name: RSClientPrint.dll,version: 2005.90.4035.0, time stamp: 0x492b18a3
Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0001741e

Faulting process id: 0x530

Faulting application start time: 0x01cee51eb59fe612

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\RSClientPrint.dll

Report Id: f6fae729-5111-11e3-bbba-000c29735f93

And I have tried these solutions

1.Updated SQL server with

- Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 SP1 Redistributable
  Report Viewer Redistributable 2008 Service Pack 1 GDIPLUS.DLL Security Update

2.Deploy the control manually

- Extract the files From C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\rsclientprint.cab 
  and  copies those files to  Windows\Downloaded Program Files\
- then Register RSClientPrint.dll by opening a command line  regsvr32
  RSClientPrint.dll

But those Solutions not worked.

Is there alternative solution for fix this problem

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  I've tried all of the recommended solutions like installing the service packs for SQL Server and Report Server, and also updating the report viewer.  If I run IE9 on one of our servers that has no Windows updates installed, then the print control works fine.  At this point I believe a Windows update package is the culprit.

Comment: We had the same issue on SQL 2008R2 RTM and the issue was the service pack version on the SQL Server, not IE 10. I had to upgrade to Sql Server 2008 R2 SERVICE PACK 2. Are you on the latest SP for your SQL version? 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031060/reportviewers-print-button-incompatible-with-ie-10

Comment: As solution for this i have upgraded my SQL server 2005 to SQL server 2008 R2 with SP2.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the 'print' icon from ReportingServices by setting `display: none !important;` on it's CSS style, or by removing the users permission to it.

The ActiveX print control does not have any practical value, and does more harm than good anyway.

My only other suggestion would be uninstalling and reinstalling ReportViewer on the client machine.
Some IE update might have damaged it, or a ReportingService ServicePack may have broken backward compatibility.

Or it might start to work if you set the page into IE5-Quirksmode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

In ReportViewer.aspx, which is somewhere like here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<instance name>\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages\ReportViewer.aspx
```

If they absolutely want to print it, they can export the report to PDF/Excel and print from Acrobat Reader.

Btw, removing the print icon (for languages German, French, Italian, English in this example) goes like this (in 2008 R1):

```
input[type="image"][title="Drucken"], input[type="image"][title="Print"], input[type="image"][title="Imprimer"], input[type="image"][title="Stampa"]
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

You find more evil SSRS hacks here:

[SSRS Report Viewer Control Browser Compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596479/ssrs-report-viewer-control-browser-compatibility/18269220#18269220)

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for this I have upgrade  SQL server 2005 to
SQL server 2008 R2 SP2.
It fixed the printing issue.
thank you