# The selected report is not ready for viewing. The report is still being rendered or a report snapshot is not available. (rsReportNotReady)

Tags: reporting-services

I am encountering the Error mentioned on subject everytime i use the interactive sorting on the exported .HTML file.

Here's the scenario. I have a report(with an interactive sorting column) which i created a subscription to run and generate an .HTML format every 2 minutes.
I would like to know if the interactive sorting feature will still work on the .HTML that was generated? Let me know your thoughts and tricks if ever.

Thanks.

Comment: You can export the report to HTML manually from the reporting services website to see if it is sortable. The export to html feature on the website will be the same as that produced by the subscription.

Comment: pchan-ie - i had tried your recommendation many times but still encountering the error. I exported the report to HTML manually from reporting services website and opened the HTML file and clicked the sorting icon then the error in subject occured.

Comment: Does the interactive sorting work when you view the report with report view/Preview

Comment: Are you using internet explorer to open the html page? What errors do you see in the console window when you run F12 developer tools.

Comment: Yes it is working on the Report preview, I also uploaded it on the SSRS Report manager and it is also working.

Comment: i am using IE 11 in opening the HTML file. Here is the error i've got from the console window "The attached page targets document mode 5. Some console APIs and features may not be available" HTML1202: http://ampicamtestodb1/ReportServer_TEST1?%2Fbsola%2FPROD_EQUIPMENT_STATUS_TEST_ANNEX&rs%3AFormat=HTML4.0&rs%3ASnapshot%3Aisnull=True&rs%3ACommand=Sort&rc%3AUseFullUrls=True&rc%3AToolbar=False&rc%3AActiveXControls=False&rs%3ASortId=40iT0&rs:SortDirection=Ascending&rs:ClearSort=True is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked.

Comment: DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing compatibility view setting for intranet sites if you can.

Also check to see if your browser and os support the interactive features of SSRS [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx), there is a table at the bottom of that page.

There is a long rant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596479/ssrs-report-viewer-control-browser-compatibility) that discusses the problems with rendering SSRS report in HTML. It also show some workarounds you can do with jquery.

If all that fails, just render your reports in Excel, your users can filter it and sort it any way they want.